# Adding an Attribute to a Script Tag Before Src

Tags: theming, javascript

I'm working with CloudFlare and have identified a script that needs the `data-cfasync=“false”` attribute applied so CF doesn't touch it.

This script is defined in a library in a custom module.

```
my-custom-library:
  version: 1.x
  header: true
  js:
    //path/to/external/library.js: { type: external, weight: -400, attributes: { data-cfasync: "false" } }
```

I can get the attribute on the script tag in question but it's always after the `src`. Per the [CloudFlare requirements](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169436-How-can-I-have-Rocket-Loader-ignore-specific-JavaScripts-) it needs to go before `src`.

How can I can move this attribute to where it needs to go?